# Form.Control.Feedback is not working for file input

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

i am working with React-bootstrap 1.4.0, issue is that Form.Control.Feedback is not displaying the error, this is the image
[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV99q.png)

its working fine for input of type text.....

this is the code :

```
<Row className="my-2">
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="admin-pdf-file">
          <Form.File id="cf_fileInput" custom>
            <Form.File.Input id="cf_fileInput" name="pdfFile" type="file" className="form-control border-radius-edit bg-secondary" onChange={handleFileSelect} required />
            <Form.File.Label htmlFor="cf_fileInput" data-browse="Upload">
              {pdfFileName.map(name => name.name)}
            </Form.File.Label>
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="isvalid" isInvalid={Boolean(errors !== null)}>{errors != null ? errors.map(error => (
              error.msg.param === "fileUpload" && error.msg.message
            )) : "Please Upload File"}</Form.Control.Feedback>
          </Form.File>
        </Form.Group>
      </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove required in your Form.File.Input.
Required is evaluated before bootstrap's style.

As described in [react boostrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/forms/#form-file-props) example it lacks Form.Group component.
This is the implementation:

```
<Form.Group controlId="admin-pdf-file">
    <Form.File custom>
      <Form.File.Label>File name</Form.File.Label>
      <Form.File.Input isInvalid />
      <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Please Upload File</Form.Control.Feedback>
    </FormFile>
</Form.Group>
```